# Virtual Host Subsites apache 2.4

Tags: wordpress, apache

I'm setting up 2 wordpress sites. The scenario is that there are two Wordpress installations, in the folder var/www/domain/us and var/www/domain/eu. The domain.com/us should be the default option when you access the site from domain.com
Users access the site through: domain.com/us or domain.com/eu

Right now the setup for virtual host is: (I don't have a real domain name attached, so its only IP address so far)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName [IP-address]
 ServerAlias [IP-address]
 DocumentRoot /var/www/domain/us
 ErrorLog /var/www/html/domain.com/logs/error.log
 CustomLog /var/www/html/domain.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName [IP-address]/us
 DocumentRoot /var/www/domain/us
 ServerAlias [IP-address]
 ErrorLog /var/www/html/domain.com/logs/error.log
 CustomLog /var/www/html/domain.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName [IP-address]/eu
 DocumentRoot /var/www/domain/eu
 ServerAlias [IP-address]
 ErrorLog /var/www/html/domain.com/logs/error.log
 CustomLog /var/www/html/domain.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I can access the IP address with the primary virtual host, but the last two IP/us and IP/eu is giving Page not found.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

ServerName interprets the path as part of the hostname. Server name can contain the request scheme, hostname and port, but not the path. Therefore only the first virtual host is valid.

Since you are on Apache 2.4, you can use conditional directives to solve the problem. In the first virtual host add the following, and then remove the other two:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName [IP-address]
 ServerAlias [IP-address]
 <If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/eu.*$#">
   DocumentRoot /var/www/domain/eu
 </If>
 <Else>
   DocumentRoot /var/www/domain/us
 </Else>
 ErrorLog /var/www/html/domain.com/logs/error.log
 CustomLog /var/www/html/domain.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It now throws me an error when i restart the apache service: AH00526: Syntax error on line 21 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domain.com.conf:
DocumentRoot not allowed here
 - Any ideas?

Comment: I am also working on this problem and got the exact same error. On paper this seems like the perfect solution, but I can't fathom -- would Apache really forbid the setting of DocumentRoot within an <If> statement?

Comment: Actually, @William Greenly, your answer here is wrong, and cannot work. The Apache docs say that only directives valid in a "directory" context or higher are allowed for use in <If> <Else> sections. The docs say "Only directives that support the directory context can be used within [the <If>] configuration section." (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#if) Unfortunately, the DocumentRoot directive is only allowed in "server config" and "virtual host" contexts (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#documentroot). Bummer!